# How do I delete everything in /var/mail/username from the command line?

Tags: mail

As a result of a long-running cron job, I have over 1,000 messages in my user's mailbox. What's the easiest way to delete them?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you want to delete all the messages, you can simply truncate the mailbox file for a user with the following command:

```
> /var/mail/username
```

(the greater than sign is not a prompt: you are in effect redirecting the output of nothing to the file, which will truncate it).

Answer (score 14):

Run mail in a terminal. Press d 1-. This will delete those messages.

Removing files for managing mail is like adjust the volume of your tv with a hammer. It may work, but it is not optimal and far too brutal.

Comment: _This_ is the correct answer. It also allows deleting just some emails, if it's unclear from the command. E.g. `d 1-100` will delete the first 100 email messages.

Comment: I had to install `mailutils` and then use `d *` on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It was `d *` on centos 8 after installing `mailx`

Comment: When I type `mail`, I get the message "No mail for <user>" and cannot access the mail console

Comment: @AisteruFirë What are you attempting to do? I have a feeling that you should ask a new question, where you explain in some more detail, because you probably don't want to delete mail.

Comment: @vidarlo I saw the "You have new mail" message on login, used `mail` to read it, then quit. I got the message that the message was stored in `$HOME/mbox`, and wanted to go and delete it.
I realized that this was a simple file, so I just deleted it, but before doing so I thought I had to go back through `mail` to delete it.